# Read cookie to login automatic

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I store the cookies when someone is logging in, as below:

```
List<User> listUser;
//returns 1 user
foreach(User u in listUser)
{
   HttpCookie cookieNickname = new HttpCookie("UserNickname");
   cookieNickname.Value = u.Nickname.ToString();
   cookieNickname.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
   Response.Cookies.Add(cookieNickname);

   HttpCookie cookiePassword = new HttpCookie("UserPassword");
   cookiePassword.Value = u.Password;
   cookiePassword.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
   Response.Cookies.Add(cookiePassword);
}
```

When someone visits the site again, I want to read data from the database which is associated with usernickname-cookie and userpassword-cookie.

Then I want to show the firstname and lastname on a label.

This is what I tried:

```
List<User> cookieLoggedInUser;

if (Request.Cookies["UserNickname"] != null && Request.Cookies["UserPassword"] != null)
    {
        //returns 1 user
        cookieLoggedInUser = Database.SignIn(Request.Cookies["UserNickname"].ToString(), Request.Cookies["UserPassword"].ToString());

        if (cookieLoggedInUser.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (User u in cookieLoggedInUser)
            {
                lblFirstName.Text = u.FirstName;
                lblLastName.Text = u.LastName;
            }
        }
    }
```

But both of the Request.Cookies return null.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend the approach you took other then for experimeting purposes as it has big security risk.

To make your curent solution work check that you are creating cookies in the same domain where you consume them.

If it is not the case, browser will not send cookies to the other domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the sign-in cookie permanent using a technique like this:

```
protected void Login1_OnLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox Remember = (CheckBox)((Login)sender).FindControl("Remember");
    if (Remember.Checked)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket t = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(2, Login1.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(5), true, "");
        string data = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(t);
        HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, data);
        authCookie.HttpOnly = true;
        authCookie.Domain = "";
        authCookie.Expires = t.Expiration;
        Response.Cookies.Remove("FORMAUTH");
        Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
        Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
    }
}
```

This assumes the site is using asp.net membership services.

The line that says `Response.Cookies.Remove("FORMAUTH");` should match the cookie name you have set up in your web.config under this section:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" name="FORMAUTH"/>
</authentication>
```

Wire this up to the `OnLoggedIn` event of your `<asp:Login>` control and when the user clicks Remember Me they stay logged in.

This is a lot safer than the alternative which you propose (storing unencrypted passwords in cookies).

Comment: But how can I on page load read the cookie to get the data from the person that is logged in?

Comment: If you are using asp.net membership you just check `Request.IsAuthenticated`